# slick.js slider fade effect bug not working properly

Tags: slider, fade, slick.js

I am using slick slider with the option `fade: true`, but it is not working properly: for example if the next slide is smaller then the previous, the exceeding part of that image remains visible for a little time and the effect just look ugly... I do not if it is a bug or I need just to set it properly

```js
$('.fade').slick({
  fade: true,
  dots: true,
  infinite: true
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.6/slick.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.6/slick.min.js"></script>


<div class="fade">
  <div>
    <img src="//static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2012/3/6/1331051759134/Blue-sky-with-clouds-007.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Sky-View_ForestWander.JPG" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="//img.theepochtimes.com/n3/eet-content/uploads/2013/12/blue-sky-shutterstock-110494415-WEBONLY.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5a0eqp7/)